# Orange Changes the data type

Tags: data-mining, predictive-modeling, dataset, orange

I have a column as month in my excel data set, when i load the data in the file, orange changes it to some numerical values.. Help! I want the Month as it is. Tried changing the value type as short or long date in excel too.

The orange loads Dec-16 as 42055.00 something.

Comment: Can you share (a relevant part of) a row of your data, verbatim?

Comment: What program are you using? What is orange? Did you google this?

Comment: Note : The Orange Data Mining does not change data type if you import dataset in .csv file

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I was told to avoid Excel as it did not conform to the ISO 8601 standard of 2016-12-27.

Then I transferred the data to Google Sheets as illustrated in Orange tutorial YouTube videos.

The dates were altered to match the required format however the results remain exactly the same.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue when attempting to view temporal data on the scatterplot.

Perhaps Excel is outputting a [`DATEVALUE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252)

I tried some Excel magic to create columns with Text conforming to the ISO 8601 standard -> This looked promising, but data in these columns could not be assigned as a datetime variable in orange.

In the end I got [around the issue](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YEAR-function-c64f017a-1354-490d-981f-578e8ec8d3b9) by adding columns using the "year" and "month" functions in Excel.